# How do I manage resolv.conf with Puppet and NetworkManager?

Tags: dns, networkmanager, puppet

I have some hosts that have explicitly managed `resolv.conf` files. I have others that rely on NetworkManager, which does many things including writing the `resolv.conf file`.

Is there a consistent way to manage this information with Puppet, such as some module where I can describe the DNS servers and search orders semantically, then expect the right thing to happen depending on how the host is configured?

Failing that, is there a module that will interface to NetworkManager to do what I want? Writing out an explicit `resolv.conf` file is fairly trivial, so I need no help with that if I go that route.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using NetworkManager, it typically manages `/etc/resolv.conf` so you don't want to manage that directly with puppet. Instead you want to manage the configuration files which are a bit distribution dependent.

But the upstream default format of configuration is stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and in that directory you can drop new configuration files e.g. with puppet. Another way is to make it talk to NetworkManager via API (whether directly via D-Bus or through `libnm`, or even `nmcli`).

There is still the option of setting `dns=none` in the main section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and handling `resolv.conf` yourself.